# How to check whether a word is composed of other strings in an array

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I want to check whether a string is built from another two strings within a given string set.

For example, given the following array:

```
var arr = new string[] { "b", "at", "bat", "ct", "ll", "ball", "ba"};
```

I want to return only **"bat"** and **"ball"**.

That's because they can be composed from two other elements in the array like so:

```
"bat" = "b" + "at"
"ball" = "ba" + "ll"
```

I have tried doing it with a foreach loop, but I'm not quite getting it right. 
Any help will be much appreciated.

I have done something like

```
foreach(var x in list)
{
    if (dataaccess.IsThreeCharacters(x))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i; j < arr.Length; j++)
            {
                if(x == arr[i] + arr[j])
                {
                    newlist.Add(x);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's with the smart quotes?

Comment: Could you post the code you've tried?

Comment: Should it be case sensitive?  Does it have to be **exactly** two?  What if you had {"b", "a", "t"}... should "bat" match in that case?

Comment: @Brandon I have updated the question, please have a look

Comment: @JosephStyons It should be using two characters, matching the case not necessary

Comment: Looks like you need to write some unit tests for this, it might actually help you solve the problem in your code.

Comment: @huMptyduMpty: From your example, it seems like you are interested in elements of **`arr`** which can be composed from other elements of **`arr`**. So what does `list` contain then? Also, what's the deal with `IsThreeCharacters`? You didn't mention this anywhere.

Comment: sorry guys, my bad it just problem with the second for loop it should be **int j= 0**

Comment: @huMptyduMpty: that's right, you were not iterating through all elements. As a side note, this will be *very* inefficient if your dictionary starts to grow, but as usual, you can leave performance tweaks for later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will give you all of the values that can be composed from other values in the sequence:

```
var values = new HashSet<string>(new[] { "b", "at", "bat", "ct", "ll", "ball", "ba" });

var compositeValues =
    from value in values
    from otherValue in values
    where value != otherValue
    let compositeValue = value + otherValue
    where values.Contains(compositeValue)
    select compositeValue;
```

Notice the use of `HashSet<string>`, which gives O(1) lookup performance, as opposed to the O(N) of an array.

Comment: This will list each value twice. You can simply use `let compositeValue = value + otherValue` because `value` and `otherValue` will switch places after a while. Regarding the `HashSet` performance, this is still a O(n2) algorithm.

Comment: @Groo: Good catch, I changed my answer originally to remove some unnecessary complexity and missed that `from`. Thanks.

Comment: I made a mistake also: it's O(n*n) complexity, actually. But HashSet does improve it.

Comment: @Groo: You are right. I was referring to the performance of a single lookup for a composite value, which is the bottleneck in this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

This should work although I'm not vouching for efficiency!

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var arr = new string[] { "b", "at", "bat", "ct", "ll", "ball", "ba" };

        var composites = from s in arr
                         from lhs in arr
                         from rhs in arr
                         where s == string.Concat(lhs, rhs)
                         select s;

        foreach (var composite in composites)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(composite);                
        }
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
```